# How to arrange correctly?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create two banners with cropped corners, but I'm having problems with my code:
https://codepen.io/Jeerjmin/pen/VdBVKL

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
}

.banner-1 {
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 70px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid #01579B 4px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.banner-1:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  min-width: 38px;
  height: 60px;
  top: 39px;
  left: 303px;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: solid #01579B 4px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}


.banner-2 {
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 70px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid #01579B 4px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.banner-2:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  min-width: 38px;
  height: 60px;
  top: 39px;
  left: 652px;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: solid #01579B 4px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}


img {
  position: relative;
  top:100px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

.dot {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: -50px;
  bottom: 100px;
  text-align:center;
}


p {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="banner-1">
  <p>Card-1</p>
  <img src="https://img2.goodfon.ru/original/1366x768/6/5e/koshka-kot-meyn-kun-belyy-fon-5567.jpg"></img>

<span class="dot dot-1">
  <h1>0,5</h1>
  <h5>кг</h5>
</span>
</div>

<div class="banner-2">
  <p>Card-2</p>
  <img src="https://img2.goodfon.ru/original/1366x768/6/5e/koshka-kot-meyn-kun-belyy-fon-5567.jpg"></img>

<span class="dot dot-2">
  <h1>0,5</h1>
  <h5>кг</h5>
</span>
</div>

</div>
```

**Problem 1:**

I'm trying to crop the top left corners of the banners, but the cards move around while the crops stay where they are.

**Problem 2:**

The span with `class="dot"` should form a colored circle, but does not.

Comment: I think you should add `position: relative;` to ".banner-1" and ".banner-2". You can then add `position: absolute;` to your dot and the image for the cropped corner, to place them in the correct locations.

Comment: mfluehr, i tried it this...

Comment: See my full answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you meant in Problem 1. As for problem 2, you need to add `display: block` to your `.dot` class and you also can remove `left` property form it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make several changes to your code to get this working, so see the code snippet below for all the changes. However, here are a few key points:

- To position your `::before` pseudo-elements in correct relation to the banners, add relative positioning to the banners.
- To make your blue dot work, and to align its contents correctly, Flexbox layout is a good solution.
- To simplify your code, it's preferable to style similar items together. For that reason, I've given your banners shared styles.
- `<img>` elements should not have a corresponding closing tag (the technical term for this kind of element is "self-closing"). That said, I changed your image to be a background image. The reason is that you can't both have `overflow: hidden` on your banners **and** put the clipped corner over its borders.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Target both banners together,
   since they share styles */
.banner-1,
.banner-2 {
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 70px;
  border: 4px solid #01579B;
  border-radius: 15px;

  /* Relatively position the banner,
     so that the clipped corners,
     can be properly placed */
  position: relative;

  /* To have the image clip to
     the banner, make it a
     background image */
  background: white no-repeat 10px bottom / auto 150px
    url("https://img2.goodfon.ru/original/1366x768/6/5e/koshka-kot-meyn-kun-belyy-fon-5567.jpg");
}

.banner-1::before,
.banner-2::before {
  content: "";
  width: 22px;
  height: 38px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -1px;
  background-color: white;
  border-right: 4px solid #01579B;
  
  /* Adjust your transform origin,
     to make the rotation easier */
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.dot {
  /* Use Flexbox to align the
     content in your dot */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 100px;
}

h1, h5 {
  /* Remove margins on
     dot content */
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="banner-1">
  <p>Card-1</p>
  <span class="dot dot-1">
    <h1>0,5</h1>
    <h5>кг</h5>
  </span>
</div>

<div class="banner-2">
  <p>Card-2</p>
  <span class="dot dot-2">
    <h1>0,5</h1>
    <h5>кг</h5>
  </span>
</div>

</div>
```